# How to call diff formgroup from onchange function

Tags: angular, formgroups

I have created a common function for upload image. It works fine for single form but now I have create two forms on same component and I am trying to avoid repeated code.

```
  onFileChange(pFileList: File[]){
    this.picture = Object.keys(pFileList).map(key => pFileList[key]);
    this.uploads.fileUploading(this.picture, this.pictureInfo ,'file', 'picture');
    if (this.pictureInfo.value.file.name != '') {
      this.pictureNameOnUpload = this.pictureInfo.value.file.name;
      this.changeDetection.detectChanges();
    }
  }
```

this.pictureInfo is a formgroup

```
  pictureInfo = new FormGroup({
    picture: new FormControl("", [Validators.nullValidator]),
    file: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  });
```

Now I want to replace this.pictureInfo in parameter so i can call it from html side like below

```
      onFileChange(pFileList: File[], formName){
        this.picture = Object.keys(pFileList).map(key => pFileList[key]);
        this.uploads.fileUploading(this.picture, formName ,'file', 'picture');
}
```

But I am unable to do so. I have added the formGroup in change function but getting error.

```
<input type="file" formControlName="picture"  class="d-none"  id="picture" (change)="onFileChange($event.target.files, pictureInfo)" [multiple]="false">
```

I tried to find the solution but I am confuse how to search this one. Can anyone help me that how i can send the formGroup dynamic from change function.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What error are you getting, and when? How are you calling the onFileChange method?

Comment: Sorry I am just confuse. I just want to send fromgroup dynamically

Comment: I just don't understand in what way though. Do you want to be able to send both forms, at the same time, with the same function? Or do you want to use one function to be able to send either?

Comment: @paddotk I want to with the same function but not on the same time. I just want to use this function for both form upload image. Like a generic function for upload image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer thanks for the help. this[formName]

```
onFileChange(pFileList: File[], formName){
        this.picture = Object.keys(pFileList).map(key => pFileList[key]);
        this.uploads.fileUploading(this.picture, this[formName] ,'file', 'picture');
}
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer as the right one. This will mark the solution and close the question ;)

Comment: @paddotk I can accept my answer after two days. I don't know why it like this.